# pyplot color chart of 2d function domain

Tags: matplotlib

How can I make a 2-d color plot of the domain of a function across two dimensions? Something like this:

```
def f(x):
  return x[0]**2+6*x[1]**2+x[0]*x[1]+np.sin(x[0])+3*x[0]
x = np.arange(-5,5,0.1)
y = np.arange(-5,5,0.1)
plt.contours(x,y,f([x,y])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your last line to

`plt.contour(f(np.meshgrid(x,y)))`

That will evaluate `f` across a meshed grid of x and y and plot contours of that function. The tutorial on producing contour plots in matplotlib [is here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html).  In general, the tutorials there are pretty good and you can often find what you want.

If you want the axes labelled with the ranges in your `x` and `y` ranges - you need

```
plt.contour(x,y,f(np.meshgrid(x,y)))
```

You could instead do `plt.pcolormesh(f(np.meshgrid(x,y)))` if you prefer a 'heatmap' style to a contour plot.

For fun, I expanded the range and amplified the sin component in your function and produced a contour map and a heatmap (see output)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return x[0]**2+6*x[1]**2+x[0]*x[1]+150*np.sin(x[0])+3*x[0]

x = np.arange(-50,50,0.1)
y = np.arange(-50,50,0.1)

plt.contour(x,y,f(np.meshgrid(x,y)))

plt.show()
```

#### Contour output

[image: Contour plot]

#### `pcolormesh` output

[image]

Comment: How can I plot this with the correct axes limits? I was expecting x and y to range from -5 to 5, not 0 to 1000.

Comment: oops - sorry - I expanded the range for effect.  Change the ranges in x and y.  To change the limits on the axes - use [`plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axis) or `plt.xlim()`, `plt.ylim()` to set x and y independently.